# HTML Email Status won't get created if setWhatId() for Messaging.SingleEmailMessage is specified

Tags: apex, email, html, singleemailmessage, email-tracking

In my org I've set up an automatic process that sends email messages with the Custom template (with the HTML) to the contact. It has triggered similar code:

```
OrgWideEmailAddress addr = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'info@myorgaddress.com'];
EmailTemplate template = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'CUSTOM_HTML_TEMPLATE'];
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> composedMessages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setTemplateId(template.Id);
email.setWhatId('5001G00000dZrHh');
email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(addr.Id);
email.setTargetObjectId('0031G00000rsMgZ');
composedMessages.add(email);
Messaging.sendEmail(composedMessages);
```

Where WhatId is the Id of the Case, where messages were sent from and TargetObjectId - is the Id of the receiving Contact.

Until 1st of February 2019 both Activities and HTML Email Statuses were created, but then HTML States stopped being inserted. Even though receiver Contact receives the message, and it is listed in a Case Emails, and Contact Activities.

What I've tried:

1) Sending email message to the same contact directly from case manually using VisualForce interface. HTML Status was created with the Activity for the Contact.

2) Sending email message without setWhatId() method. HTML Status was created with the Activity for the Contact. But, obviously, message was sent without filling crucial information from the Case.

3) Tried to add

```
email.setSaveAsActivity(true);
```

to the code above, but it didn't help me.

As a last resort, thinking about trying to do this without setWhatId() but with editing substring from the html/text body directly with values from the queried case fields, but it won't be a smart solution.

Thanks in advance!

Typical situation in a Contact page, when executing this method from the console. No HTML Status, but there is a Activity record:

[image: Typical situation in a Contact, when executing this method from the console. No HTML Status, but there is a Activity record]

Comment: are you sure that you have set correct What Id? which organization you are working on? is this developer edition and you have exceeded email allocation limit?

Comment: @Patlatus yes, i am certain, because in a specified Case i see a new Email message being sent with all info needed from the Case field filled out.

Comment: That's a Production Org

Comment: I tried to implement the same solution and it works for me, what is the code for your template? maybe there is some error in template? did you modify template recently? do you receive any exception when you try to execute this code from anonymous console?

Comment: I am executing this code from anonymous console without any exceptions

Comment: so what exactly is the issue? email is sent but merge template fields are stripped? could you please update your question to include email template code snippet and corresponding email snippet received?

Comment: I doubt, that it's a template issue. I've described, that I've tried to send the same message to the same Contact from the same Case with the same EmailTemplate, and it went well, new HTML Status was created

Comment: also have you checked Known issues if there is a similar known issue to the problem you describe here https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?tag=Messaging? I see that there may be two related known issues https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000003Ul5QAE&title=restrict-usage-of-salesforce-classic-html-based-email-templates-to-secure-browsers-does-not-apply-to-email-quick-action or https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IYu7QAG&title=email-template-case-thread-id-in-an-email-template-is-stripped

Comment: The issue is that HTML Status (I need it for tracking email Opens) isn't created when I'm sending this Email using apex

Comment: if you provided email template code we could identify if you are using Case Thread Id or some other exact fields from Case or Contact which might cause the problems.

Comment: @Patlatus I've added template HTML code to the main post

Comment: I think you should contact Salesforce Support. If you have production user, you should have Salesforce Premier Support to create Support tickets related to such functionality. I can't find in knows issues anything similar to the issue you are describing.

Comment: if Salesforce support identifies an issue and creates a new known issue or mention some existing known issue then please answer your question and include link to known issue provided by Salesforce support team.

Answer (score 0):

I got it done by pre-rendering email message using renderStoredEmailTemplate() method with the caseId specified as whatId (to pre-fill template with the Case info), not sending it but copying the content of rendered email message to the new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage without specified whatId.

That caused sent emails to insert an HTML status, therefore be trackable:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage renderedEmail = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(
        getTemplateToDebtor(),
        getOrCreateInvoicingContact(), 
        cs.Id); 

emailToSend.setHtmlBody(renderedEmail.getHtmlBody());
emailToSend.setPlainTextBody(renderedEmail.getPlainTextBody());
emailToSend.setSubject(renderedEmail.getSubject());
emailToSend.setCcAddresses(addCCAddresses());
emailToSend.setBccAddresses(CasePlugIns.ccAddresses(cs));
emailToSend.setFileAttachments(fileAttachments);
emailToSend.setTargetObjectId(getOrCreateInvoicingContact());
emailToSend.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(getOweaId());
```